# Unable to connect conceptnet5 database in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

After installing ConceptNet5.5 using Docker as mentioned on the link https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Running-your-own-copy, when I run the search query from browser I get the following error.

[image]

My system IP is `10.201.23.66`

---

Both of the containers are running.

```
 $ sudo docker ps
```

**CONTAINER ID        IMAGE           COMMAND         CREATED           STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES**

```
b4a07f4d3fcb       rspeer/conceptnet:5.5.5        "/usr/bin/supervis..."   57 seconds ago      Up 55 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   conceptnet5master_api_1

d4f95d53ef90        rspeer/conceptnet-data:5.5.5   "docker-entrypoint..."   2 days ago          Up 57 seconds       5432/tcp                                   conceptnet5master_db_1
```

---

In the log file, I am getting the following message -

> **api_1  | Database 'conceptnet5' is not available, retrying for 10 seconds
>
> api_1  | [pid: 30|app: 0|req: 4/10] 10.201.51.101 () {42 vars
>   in 755 bytes} [Mon Apr  9 18:38:30 2018] GET
>   /search?rel=/r/synonym&start=c/en/masculine => generated 2338 bytes in
>   10015 msecs (HTTP/1.1 503) 3 headers in 130 bytes (1 switches on core
>   0)
>
> api_1  | 10.201.51.101 - - [09/Apr/2018:18:38:40 +0000] "GET
>   /search?rel=/r/synonym&start=c/en/masculine HTTP/1.1" 503 2338 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/59.0"**

---

When I try to access the conceptnet5 database using the following command

```
$ sudo docker exec -it d4f95d53ef90  psql -U postgres conceptnet5
```

It gives me the following prompt -

```
conceptnet5=#
```

And when I run `\dt` on that, it results in -

```
No relations found.
```

Please explain what is causing the error.